# C++ int & long marshalling in C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm currently porting a proprietary dll (an API) to C#, and I have some problems when marshalling some of the used data types.

For example the API header file defines the following types:

```
typedef unsigned int  tINT;  /* natural unsigned */
typedef signed int    tINTs; /* natural signed */
typedef unsigned int  tLONG; /* 32 bit unsigned */
typedef unsigned long tPTR;  /* 32/64-bit pointer */
```

Then I for example have the following function definition:

```
tINTs SomeApiFunction ( const tPTR hdl, tINT param );
```

I'm usually marshalling the `int` directly with C#'s `int` (`Int32`), or the unsigned version. The API's `tLONG` and `tINT` are as such the same (at least for the API). But I'm not sure with the `tPTR`. I have now made it a `uint` in C#, because it is a 32bit int, but I'm not sure how the `long` would behave on a 64bit machine.

What do I have to do to make sure that the API will work on both 32bit and 64bit machines correctly?

This is what I would have done now:

```
[DllImport( "api.dll" )]
public static extern int SomeApiFunction ( uint hdl, uint param );
```

Sadly the API is not really well documented, as such I am not sure what the intention was with all those (overlapping) typedefs. Apart from the header comments I have included above there is no information about the actual types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to Marshal it as an `IntPtr`. IntPtr is 4 bytes on a 32bit system and 8 bytes on a 64bit system in .Net.

Comment: Oh, just a quick additional question: Should I use `IntPtr` or `UIntPtr` given that the pointer there is an *unsigned* long?

Comment: Unless you have problems dealing with negative values due to pointer arithmetics you should still use IntPtr. From msdn docs: The IntPtr type is CLS-compliant, while the UIntPtr type is not. Only the IntPtr type is used in the common language runtime. The UIntPtr type is provided mostly to maintain architectural symmetry with the IntPtr type.

Answer (score 3):

It is an implementation detail of the C/C++ compiler.  You should go by the comment and declare it IntPtr.  If the code is compiled by the MSVC compiler then it isn't going to work in 64-bit mode, it uses 32-bits for a long.  Not enough to store a pointer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, it is not going to work on 64bit? My example C# code, or the whole API (wouldn't surprise me tbh.)?

Comment: The whole API and thus your C# example too.  Do you have a pre-built 64-bit version of that DLL?  You can typically poke around and have an idea how it was built.

Comment: No, I have just the one DLL.. :/

Comment: Well, don't worry about it then.  You have to set the C# project's Target Platform to x86.  Use IntPtr, maybe they'll fix it some day.

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll try to contact the vendor at some later point; for now it will be good enough to work with x86 only. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is [good list of type correspondence.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

For pointer types is usually `IntPtr` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly `int` `uint` and other primitive types are the right type for the underlying windows API.

For pointers however, its best to use `IntPtr` on C# side and `void*` on C/C++ side.